# does restrict background data hurt performance of phone

Tags: battery

Do I "restrict background data" yes or no and does it have more negative side effects than positive?

Comment: Consider explaining the reason behind this thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my phone's (Note 4 Edge) warning screen for "restrict background data".  The implication is that this is a feature meant to protect users with miniml plans from accidentally incurring charges.  It's also darn handy when travelling overseas or out of plan range.

I do not expect it would hamper performance, but may cause some functions to not work at all.

[image: Samsung Note Edge (4)]

Comment: Thanx  sooo much for the direct answer it helps as I am new @ this and have a very minimal plan!!!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't harm your phone..it restrict background data which means you will not receive notifications of mail or messenger while doing other stuff. And some apps like Google Play won't work.